# Regex to capture everything but consecutive newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the best way to capture everything except when faced with two or more new lines?

ex:

```
name1
address1
zipcode

name2
address2
zipcode

name3
address3
zipcode
```

One regex I considered was `/[^\n\n]*\s*/g`. But this stops when it is faced with a single `\n` character.

Another way I considered was `/((?:.*(?=\n\n)))\s*/g`. But this seems to only capture the last line ignoring the previous lines.

What is the best way to handle similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can consider replacing the *variable length separator* with some known *fixed length* string not appearing in your processed text and then split. For instance:

```
> var s = "Hi\n\n\nBye\nCiao";
> var x = s.replace(/\n{2,}/, "#");
> x.split("#");
["Hi", "Bye
Ciao"]
```

I think it is an elegant solution. You could also use the following somewhat contrived regex

```
> s.match(/((?!\n{2,})[\s\S])+/g);
["Hi", "
Bye
Ciao"]
```

and then process the resulting array by applying the `trim()` string method to its members in order to get rid of any `\n` at the beginning/end of every string in the array.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is capturing `Bye` as well, since it doesn't end with `\n\n` it shouldn't be captured separately. It should be part of Ciao so the result should have been `["hi","Bye\nCiao"]`

Comment: So I misunderstood you. Thanks for the clarification. I'll try to fix it. If I can't then I'll delete the answer.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. I hope it will be more helpful now.

Comment: Hi, your regex works amazingly... I will be using either your solution or Austin Brunkhorst's... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`((.+)\n?)*`(you probably want to make the groups non-capturing, left it as is for readability)

The inner part `(.+)\n?` means "non-empty line" (at least one non-newline character as . does not match newlines unless the appropriate flag is set, followed by an optional newline)

Then, that is repeated an arbitrary number of times (matching an entire block of non-blank lines).

However, depending on what you are doing, regexp probably is not the answer you are looking for. Are you sure just splitting the string by `\n\n` won't do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Do you *have* to use regex? The solution is simple without it.

```
var data = 'name1...';

var matches = data.split('\n\n');
```

To access an individual sub section split it by `\n` again.

```
//the first section's name
var name = matches[0].split('\n')[0];
```

Comment: That would have been good enough if the number of `\n` was assured, but it can be two or more.... but I suppose I could `strip` each of them and then use it....